# Calling a WebMethod method inside a webservice : it made an "asynch" call?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have this method on my WebService (`.asmx`)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Test(string IDPagina)
{
   return "Hello"
}
```

now, if from another method inside the WebService :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Edit(string IDPagina)
{
   return Test("1234");
}
```

it "call" directly that `Test()` from the same "class" or it will done an "asynch" call to itself? (making a new soap connection etc..).

Just curious...

Comment: It will directly call without soap connection just like any other method in class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will call it directly like any other function.

Answer (score 2):

It will directly call without soap connection just like any other method in class

Comment: Does this answer your question? or you have something else in mind?